# Not displayed fonts while converting SVG image

Tags: c#, svg, png

I am using [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/) to convert svg image to png.
My code is working at it looks like this:

```
SvgDocument svgDoc = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(decoded);

foreach (var item in svgDoc.Children)
{
      SetFonts(item);
}

Bitmap image = svgDoc.Draw();
```

There is a known [issue](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/issues/247) with displaying a font, so I am trying to use this method:

```
 public void SetFonts(SvgElement parent)
    {
        if (parent.HasChildren())
        {
            foreach (SvgElement child in parent.Children)
            {
                SetFonts(child);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            SvgText svgText = (SvgText)parent;
            svgText.FontFamily = "Arial";
            svgText.FontSize = 12;
            svgText.Font = "Arial";
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

It finds only the **by Day** text string but still captions of axes are not visible, where might be the problem?

Ths svg file is [here](https://gist.github.com/tkowalczyk/a4d64dbb925479ea21f98b231d770162).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put CSS in the defs section. Something like:

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
      font-family: Delicious;
      src: url('../fonts/font.woff');
    }
  </style>
</defs>
```